# Making two transformation changes (scale, rotation) in iOS

Tags: ios, rotation, uiimage, scale, transformation

I'm trying to do the following transformation changes but only one seems to work: -

```
self.image1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.1);
self.image1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
```

Only the first transformation works, what do I need to do make both changes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `CGAffineTransformMake...` you are creating a new transformation. So in your code you overwrite the Rotation with the Scale transformation.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.1);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.1, 1.1);
self.image1.transform = transform;
```